# Packages no longer available for download

Tags: apt, package-management

I signed up for Ubuntu Pro and part of the sign up I executed `pro security-status`
It returned:

```
3120 packages installed:
     2220 packages from Ubuntu Main/Restricted repository
     743 packages from Ubuntu Universe/Multiverse repository
     9 packages from third parties
     148 packages no longer available for download
```

I then executed `pro security-status --unavailable`

Questions:

1. How do I establish if they are used? And if so when last?
2. How do I know if they have been replaced? `apt install [package-name]` ... all 148 of them?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS - I have been upgrading this instance since Xenial.
The 148 packages are:

```
Packages:
app-install-data-partner brother-udev-rule-type1 brscan-skey brscan3
cncupsir2006zk cncupsiradv45253zk cncupsiradv45453zk cncupsiradv5253zk
cncupsiradv525zk cncupsiradv6153zk cncupsiradv615zk cncupsiradv65553zk
cncupsiradv65753zk cncupsiradv7153zk cncupsiradv715zk cncupsiradv85053zk
cncupsiradv85853zk cncupsiradvc2563zk cncupsiradvc35203zk cncupsiradvc35253zk
cncupsiradvc4753zk cncupsiradvc55353zk cncupsiradvc55503zk cncupsiradvc75653zk
cncupsiradvc75803zk cncupslbp161zk cncupslbp211zk cncupslbp213zk cncupslbp214zk
cncupslbp215zk cncupsmf110zk cncupsmf260zk cncupsmf420zk cncupsmf520zk
cncupswg7000zk cncupswg7000zzk cndrvcups-common cndrvcups-ufr2-uk
cndrvcups-utility cpp-5 crda dmd e2fslibs enchant
evolution-data-server-online-accounts gcc-5-base gcc-6-base gcc-7-base
gcc-8-base geoclue gir1.2-signon-1.0 gnome-tweak-tool gnome-user-guide
grub-customizer gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 insync interconnect:i386 ippusbxd
libasan2 libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libbrlapi0.6 libcapnp-0.7.0 libcomerr2
libcroco3 libdvdcss-dev libdvdcss2 libenchant1c2a libexempi3 libexiv2-14 libfam0
libgeoclue0 libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libidn11
libilmbase12 libisl15 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libminiupnpc10
libmirclient9 libmircommon7 libmirprotobuf3 libmpdec2 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0
libnm-util2 libpangox-1.0-0 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libplymouth4
libprotobuf-lite17 libruby2.7 libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsepol1
libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1
libsndio6.1 libssl1.1 libubsan0 libunity-action-qt1 liburl-dispatcher1
libusbmuxd4 libvpx3 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libwinpr-dsparse0.1
libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1
libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 linux-generic-hwe-16.04
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 master-pdf-editor-5 mfc295cncupswrapper:i386
mfc295cnlpr:i386 multiarch-support net.downloadhelper.coapp nsgclient
plainbox-secure-policy projectlibre protonmail-bridge python-dbus
python3-guacamole python3-plainbox qtcore4-l10n qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin signon-plugin-password signond spotify-client
syslinux-legacy ttf-ubuntu-font-family ubuntu-system-service ureadahead webex
xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04 zoom

Thank you for the comments. Following the comment from @umu I have reduced the list to 130. When I run apt-cache policy [Package name] I am returned information on the Installed and Candidate version as follows:
 evolution-data-server-online-accounts:
  Installed: 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3
  Candidate: 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
In this instance this package is from 18.04 and can therefore be removed?
```

Comment: 1. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? 2. Run `sudo apt update` and try again

Comment: Could you in your question please list the 148 orphaned packages? There surely is an explanation..

Comment: you can use synaptic to see what version of the packages you have and to see if there is any updated versions of them.

Comment: A few of these (e.g., `gcc-*`, all the `-16.04`, `-18.04` ones) are definitely left over packages from upgrading. `gnome-tweak-tool` was replaced by `gnome-tweaks` (it was a transitional package for a while, so you should have the `gnome-tweaks` package installed).